# Why devise errors doesn't display on sign up page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I can't display devise errors. The problem happen only in sign up page. However the configuration for sign in and sign up is the same...
I display errors via the `application.html.erb`

I know the errors are properly generated because when I put `resource.errors.full_messages` at the beginning, errors are displaying. But without the style I made.

**sign up**

```
.section
  .subscribe-c.w-container
    .section-title-group
      h2.heading Bonjour !
    = simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f|
      = f.input_field :email, class: "form-field w-input", placeholder: "Email"
      = f.input_field :password, class: "form-field w-input", placeholder: "Mot de passe", html: { autocomplete: 'off' }
      = f.input_field :password_confirmation, class: "form-field w-input", placeholder: "Confirmez votre mot de passe", html: { autocomplete: 'off' }
      = f.submit "Je m'inscris", class: "button full-width w-button"
      = render "devise/shared/links"
```

[image]

**sign in** (the one who works properly)

```
.section
  .subscribe-c.w-container
    .section-title-group
      h2.heading Bonjour !
    = simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f|
      = f.input_field :email, class: "form-field w-input", placeholder: "Email"
      = f.input_field :password, class: "form-field w-input", placeholder: "Mot de passe", html: { autocomplete: 'off' }
      = f.submit "c'est parti !", class: "button full-width w-button"
      = render "devise/shared/links"
```

[image]

**application.html.erb**

```
  <body class=body>
    <% if notice %>
      <p class="alert alert-success"><%= notice %></p>
    <% end %>
    <% if alert %>
      <p class="alert alert-danger"><%= alert %></p>
    <% end %>
    <%= render 'layouts/navbar' %>
    <%= yield %>
 </body>
```

Comment: This is what I get : `#<ActionDispatch::Flash::FlashHash:0x007fe2cc6f0a70 @discard=#<Set: {}>, @flashes={}, @now=nil>`

Comment: @Iceman the flash is irrelevant in this case since it has nothing to with how simple_form displays model errors. Whats puzzling is why `simple_form_for ` is not displaying any errors.

Comment: What happens if you add the missing translations `fr.activerecord.errors.models.user.attributes.email.blank` and `fr.activerecord.errors.models.user.attributes.password.blank`?

Comment: It properly translate but still with the same style. Actually I think it should be the devise translation called and not activerecord translation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're using `f.input_field` which tells simpleform to strip away all divs around the form field.  If you switch to `f.input`, simpleform will wrap your fields in the div that Rails will look to add the error messages to.  This may break some of your styling since now all form fields will have an extra div wrapper but you can always then make your own custom error messages at the top of the form.  Ex.

```
<% if @some_object.errors.any? %>
  <ul>
     <% @some_object.errors.each do |error,msg| %>
        <li> <%=error.capitalize%>  <%=msg%></li>
     <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the correct translation is missing: `"Courriel translation missing: fr.activerecord.errors.models.user.attributes.email.blank`.

Here is a list of all French translations from Devise: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/I18n#french-devisefryml

Make sure you set your configuration appropriately based on the documentation towards the top.

Also if you are looking for specific `ActiveRecord` translations you can look at the [rails-i18n](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n) gem where you can find more French translations [here](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/fr.yml).